# VB.Net Chart created in code - how to get X value from click event on chart?

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have a chart that is created in code in a VB.Net WinForms application.  When the form runs the chart is added to a panel and displays on the form.  All is good.

I am trying to return the cursor properties for the chart, specifically I am trying to get the x-coordinate value.  I know I can use `Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).CursorX.Position` to get this value when using a chart created in the form and placed in the click event for that chart.

At the moment I have a click event for the code generated chart.  The arguments being passed are as below:

```
Private Sub chart1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _Chart.Click
```

When I step through the code, e returns the mouse position for the chart but the cursor position (`_Chart.ChartAreas(0).CursorX`) returns `"NaN"`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The ChartArea.CursorX property has nothing to do with the mouse.  A cursor is a line displayed on a chart.  You don't have one.  Very unclear what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Trying to return the X value for the chart from a click event on the chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this one.

The Chart created in code must be done WithEvents.  The method responding to the Click handler needs to be passing MouseEventArgs rather than System.EventArgs as below:

```
 Private Sub chart1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                             ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles _Chart.Click
```

The X value can be returned using

```
_Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X)
```